# Chrome download somefile.tar.gz as somefile.gz.gz, how to fix it?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome

[Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) for OS X (version 7.0.517.44) downloads a .tar.gz file and saves it as .gz.gz (e.g. http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/cck-6.x-2.8.tar.gz). Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Where can I find 9.0 of Chrome? The beta http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_beta.html?dl=mac is a 8.0... Thanks

Comment: Found 9.0 at http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel. Yes, 9.0 fixes this issue.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I convert my successful comment to an answer, even though I suggested a dev channel release, which might not necessarily be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a newer version of Chrome. You can find all channels (stable, beta, dev) [here](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel).

Answer (score 2):

It's apparently a security feature. More info in [Chromium Discussion issue # 1503](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1503).

> The double extension  (e.g.
>   filename.gz.gz) is currently
>   deliberately done, in  order to avoid
>   situations where an innocent website
>   serves a malicious file by giving  it
>   a benign extension - e.g., an
>   executable file being named as .jpeg

Comment: Nevertheless, it has been verified and accepted as a bug. Sadly, there have not been any satisfactory fixes implemented.

Comment: So it's actually File.tar.gz.gz, not File.gz.gz as the OP suggested?

Comment: It's `File.gz.gz` in my case.